# Get the same SKU from woocommerce itself for simple and variable products

Tags: php, woocommerce-offtopic

I'm trying to create a Buy Now button, everything went well, but I have the biggest problem that would be the variable products, the simple ones worked perfectly, but how do I get the skus of the products like woocommerce?

```
/*I searched the woocoomerce code found this*/
public function get_sku( $context = 'view' ) {
        return $this->get_prop( 'sku', $context );
    }
/* END */

/* Code I tried, but using get_product id */
add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'buy_now', 35 );
 
function buy_now() {
    echo "<p><a href='linkwebsite/?add-to-cart=<?php /* get_product_id */ ?>' class='button'>Buy Now</a></p>";
}
/* END */
```

Example: When I change as variations or changes sku, this would automatically be like how I repeat the process and put it in my functions?

Comment: I don't know if this is the actual problem or not, but you can't echo `<?php` tags like that: they won't run. You can just call `get_product_id()` in your buy_now function and concatenate the strings instead.

Comment: It worked, but in the variation does not change, I need to get the id dynamically, I realized that it stores no entry the id I want and change it according to the variation, would I get it and put it in a href?

Comment: but if the variation doesn’t exist he uses the post, how would I do that?